# Mysql LIKE clause and separate words in a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently use a mysql statement like the one below to search post titles.

`select * from table where title like %search_term%`

But problem is, if the title were like: `Acme launches 5 pound burger` and a user searched for `Acme`, it'll return a result. But if a user searched for `Acme burger` or `Acme 5 pound`, it'll return nothing.

Is there a way to get it to return results when a users searches for more than one word? Is `LIKE` the correct thing to use here or is there something else that can be used?

Comment: How about matching against a full text index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a REGEXP to match any of the words in your search string:

```
select *
from tbl
where
  title REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]](', REPLACE('Acme burger', ' ', '|'), ')[[:>:]]')
```

Please notice that this will not be very efficient. See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78757/1).

If you need to match every word in your string, you could use a query like this:

```
select *
from tbl
where
  title REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', REPLACE('Acme burger', ' ', '[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]'), '[[:>:]]')
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0dfa/1). But words have to be in the correct order (es. 'Acme burger' will match, 'burger Acme' won't). There's a REGEXP to match every word in any order, but it is not supported by MySql, unless you install an UDF that supports Perl regexp.

Comment: This too returns every title with the word acme in it when you search for acme burgers.

Comment: @Norman updated my answer. But if you need to match every word, in any order, there's a regexp but it is not natively supported by MySql...so another solution is needed

Answer (score 5):

To search for a string against a text collection use MATCH() and AGAINST()

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('+Acme burger*')
```

or why not RLIKE

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TITLE RLIKE 'Acme|burger'
```

or LIKE searching an array, to have a compilation of $keys

```
$keys=array('Acme','burger','pound');
$mysql = array('0');
foreach($keys as $key){
    $mysql[] = 'title LIKE %'.$key.'%'
}
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $mysql)
```

Comment: you will need a full text index though.

Comment: @nl-x What do you mean by full text index? The column type should be text? Right now its varchar.

Comment: I tried your MATCH solution. But that'll return everything with the word acme even when 'acme burger' is searched for. But that match is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is construct a SQL such that, for example:

```
select * from table where title like "%Acme%" and title like "%burger%"
```

In short: split the string and create one `like` for each part.
It might also work with replacing spaces with `%`, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is thing use perform union operation by splitting your search string based on whitespaces,

FOR Acme 5 pound,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TITLE LIKE '%ACME 5 POUND%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TITLE LIKE '%ACME%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TITLE LIKE '%5%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TITLE LIKE '%POUND%'
```

Find out a way to give the first query a priority. Or pass the above one as four separate queries with some priority. I think you are using front end tp pass query to data bases, so it should be easy for you.

Comment: Why not use `OR` instead of `UNION`?

Comment: yeah you can do that. But I don't know which one will be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$search_term = 'test1 test2 test3';
$keywords = explode(" ", preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $search_term));
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
 $wherelike[] = "title LIKE '%$keyword%' ";
}
$where = implode(" and ", $wherelike);

$query = "select * from table where $where";

echo $query;
//select * from table where title LIKE '%test1%' and title LIKE '%test2%' and title LIKE '%test3%'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in MySQL?