# Varchar with common strings in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Article, and I want to fetch only articles that have common words with the entered text.

This is the table article

```
id | article
1  | this is the first article I want to compare this word1 and this word2
2  | this is the first article I want to compare this1 and this2
```

if the given text is "hello world, this is word1"  or "my word2 and, and also word1", it should fetch the article with id=1, because the entry contains (word1 or word2) , which is already contained in the article.

So, the SQL query:

```
SELECT
    id,article
FROM
    article
WHERE 
    article LIKE :givenText
```

with :givenText='good morning word1', won't fetch article with id=1. Because SQL compares whole portions of the string.

How can look for articles, containing common strings?

**Note that I'm using PHP/MySQL**

EDIT : using `'%...%'` or `FIND_IN_SET` won't work too

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Check the accepted answer of this question, It works... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859966/mysql-like-clause-and-separate-words-in-a-field

Comment: Thank you @Nalaka526, I'm gonna check it out. ^_^